# How to dynamically filled cardviews according to device width

Tags: android-cardview

I am making an app where I want to maintain cards of fixed width. So How to dynamically filled cardviews according to device width.

For Ex. for a normal size phone there should be two column of cards and for big size screen there are three column of cards when app in portait mode in both phones.

Like this : 
[3 column cards example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVaKU.jpg)
[2 column cards example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKeTo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution,

need to use the GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.appmax.fest1.Dialogs.CustomGridView.MenuHome">

     <GridView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:columnWidth="100dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:id="@+id/gridview1"
         android:numColumns="auto_fit"
         >


     </GridView>


</RelativeLayout>
```